# exim refused: too many connections,how to set the max connection number

Tags: exim

I am a freshman,and I first use the exim4.89 on ubuntu 16.04,I found this problem ,the log show that:

`3900 SMTP>> 421 Too many concurrent SMTP connections; please try again later.
3900 LOG: connection_reject MAIN
3900   Connection from [**********] refused: too many connections
3900 Listening...`

,so where can I set the max connection number ,I didn't see any useful options in /usr/exim/configure file,thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research, if you have a problem you can post **what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/6676466).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exim's `smtp_accept_max-*` options are for controlling concurrent connections number. This parameters force each submitter to limit number of created sessions to some reasonable value. In other word that error occur not because of server misconfiguration but rather because of misconfiguration on the other side. I suppose it is some kind of mailgun that toss the messages at some insane rate.